# Minecraft Technic Pack - Respawn/Blank inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I have a recurring issue in the Technic Pack whereby occasionally when I load up my world (usually after the computer having been shut down for some time) my inventory is wiped and I am placed on the overworld spawn. The rest of the world will be exactly how I left it, except that I am standing at the spawn with a totally blank inventory.

The only pattern I can find is that it doesn't seem to start happening until I start exploring Mystcraft ages, so it might be linked to that. It seems like *something* corrupts my player info causing Minecraft to reset me, but it never causes any crashes or visible errors, and has never done this directly after a crash or out-of-memory shutdown.

Additionally, after the first few times I made sure never to exit my world whilst still in a Mystcraft age, but this seems to have no effect.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: be sure to report a bug to the technic pack creators through http://questions.technicpack.net/

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar problem; occasionally, the game will hang when I am trying to load into a MystCraft age, and then after I load, I will be at my spawn, with no items. To avoid this, what I've started doing is a "test travel" to a new MystCraft age, before I go there for real. I generally just put all my awesome gear into a chest, grab only a Linking Book back home, and then try the new age. If I get through, I know the age is "safe", and then I'll go back with my gear. If I don't, then I know the age is "corrupt" and I don't lose anything except a linking book when I respawn, empty handed, at the original overworld spawn.

This has basically solved the issue for me, but I've never had it be an issue except for the actual crash occurring as I traveled between worlds. So, I'm not sure how useful this strategy will be for you. I also noticed that if I craft four or five linking books, I think it somehow confuses Minecraft - I've started just doing one book at a time, then traveling to it to ensure that it works, and then doing the next. Maybe something about having multiple, untraveled ages is causing a problem?

Side note: I kind of "handwaved" the freezing and lost inventory away as being a side effect of traveling to ages (so, in character, sometimes when you try and travel, you wake up naked outside, unsuccessful). Heh, so now I just treat it as a feature, not a bug. :P

Comment: I experienced exactly this for the first time yesterday. My solution was to toggle NEI into "cheat mode" (I ususally leave it in recipe mode) and reproduce my inventory. It helps that I had a very specific, limited inventory when I went Mystcraft-exploring. I don't know how to avoid the problem (except never go to a Cave age! Too much memory needed!), and I have no idea what's happening to the OP - that's something I haven't experienced.

Comment: I did the same thing with the NEI - I don't normally use it, but since it was a bug, I just got my old inventory back.